# Recording audio using FileDescriptor and mediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

can anybody provide me code for recording audio using MediaRecorder of android by setting 
a file descriptor in outputfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what your problem is.

The description for the MediaRecorder's SetOutputFile method is pretty simple. It takes a FileDescriptor which you can get from a FileOutputStream which you can create if you have File object

Comment: thanks for replying i implemented it.actually i wanted to implement pause/play through appending to file using FileDescriptor but it's not working. can u help me to solve this problem. by the way above problem got solve so iam accepting your answer

Comment: Doesn't look possible using MediaRecorder - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190967/how-to-pause-capturing-video-in-android/5191105#5191105>