# How to pause capturing video in android?

Tags: android

I am completing video recording in android application, but I want to pause the recording while capturing, can anyone help me.

code for start recording is as follow

```
MediaRecorder recorder;

startRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                recorder.start();               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the code that you're using to record video. Looking at the MediaRecorder class, it doesn't seem to provide pause functionality. So you'd have to use some other class or add code to join media files.